# VHDL assigning port to signal

Tags: vhdl

I want to test my circuit with all possible cases.

When I wrote it with vector it seems that values of vector are not connected to the ports.

Is my port mapping not good?

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
LIBRARY UNISIM;
USE UNISIM.Vcomponents.ALL;
ENTITY lab11_lab11_sch_tb IS
END lab11_lab11_sch_tb;
ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF lab11_lab11_sch_tb IS 

   COMPONENT lab11
   PORT( a  :   IN  STD_LOGIC; 
          b :   IN  STD_LOGIC; 
          c :   IN  STD_LOGIC; 
          y :   OUT STD_LOGIC);
   END COMPONENT;
    SIGNAL VECTOR: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);

   SIGNAL a :   STD_LOGIC;
   SIGNAL b :   STD_LOGIC;
   SIGNAL c :   STD_LOGIC;
   SIGNAL y :   STD_LOGIC;

BEGIN

   UUT: lab11 PORT MAP(
        a => a, 
        b => b, 
        c => c,  
        y => y
   );
   stim_proc: PROCESS
   BEGIN
 VECTOR <= "000";
 stimloop : for i in 0 to 8 loop
        wait for 10ns;
        VECTOR <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, VECTOR'length)); 
        wait for 10ns;
    end loop stimloop;

      WAIT;
   END PROCESS; 
END;
```

Comment: VECTOR isn't assigned to the actuals a,b c (signals a, b and c in the testbench). Instead of assigning VECTOR to itself try `(a, b, c) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, VECTOR'length));` in aggregate assignment where the aggregate has the same length as VECTOR. Also note ` VECTOR <= "000000";` is invalid, the right expression (a string literal) has a different length than VECTOR.

Comment: Funny that the answer is in your question: "values of vector are not connected".

Answer (score 0):

Look at your test bench. You have a process that changes the value of `VECTOR`, but you have not associated this signal with those that you connected to the ports of the UUT.

You need to create some concurrent assignments that use slices of `VECTOR` to drive `a`, `b`, `c`. For example `a <= VECTOR(0);`